# Ориентация в Json c с помощью JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

let catcher = parse('subjects.json');

Есть массив:

```
<i>let days = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday"]<i>
```

Из него хочу доставть значения, с которых в последствии организовывать поиск по json. Как я это делаю:

```
<i>catcher.kn_38a.days[3].subject[1].name;<i>
```

Как хочу что бы выполнялся поиск:

```
<i>catcher.kn_38a.thursday.subject[1].name<i>
```

То есть использовал значение элемента массива, а не его индекс.
Но по итогу ошибка такая

```
 <i>console.log(catcher.kn_38a.days[3].subject[1].name);
                                    ^
 TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined <i>
```

Можно ли как-то решить данный вопрос средствами js или json?

Comment: Что в переменной `catcher` - `console.log(catcher);`?

Answer (score 1):

Обращайтесь к свойствам `catcher.kn_38a`, используя "bracket notation":

```
catcher.kn_38a[days[3]].subject[1].name
```

Что соответствует

```
catcher.kn_38a["thursday"].subject[1].name
```

или

```
catcher.kn_38a.thursday.subject[1].name
```